# Update the list of dates to have the same day

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this in my table

```
TempTable
Id    Date
 1    1-15-2010
 2    2-14-2010
 3    3-14-2010
 4    4-15-2010
```

i would like to change every record so that they have all same day, that is the 15th
like this

```
TempTable
Id    Date
 1    1-15-2010
 2    2-15-2010 <--change to 15
 3    3-15-2010 <--change to 15
 4    4-15-2010
```

what if i like on the 30th? 
the records should be

```
TempTable
Id    Date
 1    1-30-2010
 2    2-28-2010 <--change to 28 because feb has 28 days only
 3    3-30-2010 <--change to 30
 4    4-30-2010
```

thanks

Comment: So, what have you come up with so far? Or do you expect us to do everything for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can play some fun tricks with `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF`:

```
create table T (
    ID int not null,
    DT date not null
)
insert into T (ID,DT)
select 1,'20100115' union all
select 2,'20100214' union all
select 3,'20100314' union all
select 4,'20100415'

SELECT ID,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20100101',DT),'20100115')
from T

SELECT ID,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20100101',DT),'20100130')
from T
```

Results:

```
ID          
----------- -----------------------
1           2010-01-15 00:00:00.000
2           2010-02-15 00:00:00.000
3           2010-03-15 00:00:00.000
4           2010-04-15 00:00:00.000

ID          
----------- -----------------------
1           2010-01-30 00:00:00.000
2           2010-02-28 00:00:00.000
3           2010-03-30 00:00:00.000
4           2010-04-30 00:00:00.000
```

Basically, in the DATEADD/DATEDIFF, you specify the same component to both (i.e. month). Then, the second date constant (i.e. '20100130') specifies the "offset" you wish to apply from the first date (i.e. '20100101'), which will "overwrite" the portion of the date your not keeping. My usual example is when wishing to remove the time portion from a datetime value:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',<date column>),'20100101')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like

```
UPDATE TempTable
SET [Date] = DATEADD(dd,15-day([Date]), DATEDIFF(dd,0,[Date]))
```

We have a function that calculates the first day of a month, so I just addepted it to calculate the 15 instead...

Comment: that won't work for the 30th though, will it (it'll overflow the february date into march)